# modulo computation in python - int not callable?

Tags: python, modulo, callable

After reading a few errors of the type 'int not callable' on stackoverflow, I see that most errors of the type involve treating an int like a function.  I am getting this error on the following program and I'm not sure what's going on:

## find the power of n that satisfies the equation

```
for n in range(100):
    if ((2^n // 3) % 2) == 1:
        print n
```

The error traceback reads:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Please show us your error text.

Comment: I don't know what's causing your error, but the power operator is `**`, not `^`.

Comment: `2^n` is not 2 to the power of n. `2**n` is.

Comment: @robert
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @DavidJ. how are you running it when you get that? I bet you reassigned `range` by accident. Try `type(range)`. If that is the case, `del range` or restart your interpreter.

Comment: Do you have a variable named `range`?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist  I was inputting it into the command line w/o a scipt.  I just saved it in a file and ran it again, and it is working now.

Comment: @Barmar   Good catch, I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a variable named `range`, which you're assigning an integer to. So when you do

```
for n in range(100):
```

it's trying to call the integer as a function, instead of using the built-in `range` function.

The best solution is not to reuse builtin functions as variable names. But if you really want to, you can still access the original function using the `__builtin__` module.

```
import __builtin__
for n in __builtin__.range(100):
```

Answer (score 0):

**^** is python is Bitwise Exclusive Or
****** is the operator that you're looking for

```
for n in range(100):
    if ((2**n // 3) % 2) == 1:
        print n
```

as for the erorr that you're getting,

> int not callable

It's not reproducible, it's probably not these lines that's causing it